# Jquery Dynamically adding label to dynamically created checkbox

Tags: jquery, dynamic, checkbox, label

Here is my code that dynamically creates checkboxes (it works well), I now have to also add a label to each (with attr: id, same as corresponding checkbox, and Class named "Label").

```
$(function() {
var uniqueId = 1;
// will run on DOMDocumentLoaded
// check all paragraphs inside of element with id=fm
$('.click').each(function() {
    var $p = $(this);
    var divContent = $p.text();
    if (!divContent.match(/[£€\$¥*]/)) {
        // paragraph does not contain a currency symbol: skip
        return;
    }
    if ($p.find('input[type=radio]').length > 0) {
        // paragraph contains a radio button: skip
        return; 
    }
    // create a textbox element with appropriate attributes
    var $cbox = $('<input />').attr({
    type: 'checkbox',
    name: 'T' + (uniqueId++),
            id: 'T' + (uniqueId++),
    value: divContent,
        "class": 'toggletop'
    });
    // add spacing to the left
    $cbox.css('margin-left', '1em');
    // append the checkbox to the paragraph
    $p.before($cbox);

// edited below - I think the name, label  id, and label for is problematic. I do not know how to do it

var $boxLabel = $('<label for="+id+">NoNeed</label>').attr({
name: 'T' + (uniqueId++),
id: 'T' + (uniqueId++),
});
$p.after($boxLabel);
```

});});

This is the html (click buttons were generated as expected before I decided to add labels):

```
<div id="b16" class="itempackage">
<div id="copywrapper">
<img class="Small-im" src="%%GLOBAL_SiteURL%%/i/%%GLOBAL_userid%%/p/b16.jpg"  onerror="imgError(this)" />
<div class="click">%%GLOBAL_b16%%</div></div></div>
<div id="b17" class="itempackage">
<div id="copywrapper">
<img class="Small-im" src="%%GLOBAL_SiteURL%%/i/%%GLOBAL_userid%%/p/b17.jpg"  onerror="imgError(this)" />
<div class="click">%%GLOBAL_b17%%</div></div></div>
```

Those are var containing the description and price with currency sign: %%GLOBAL_b16%%

Comment: Provide us with your HTML too please and/or create a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: what have you tried? I mean - you know how to add a checkbox - why not a label?

Comment: I do not think you could see dynamicaly created elements in jsFiddle.

Comment: @gulty because I am not a programmer, and I had that code adapted from examples I found on the Web.

Comment: first of all add a dynamic ID to your inputs. then create an element (just like the input) and pass the id in the for: part. like: var boxLabel = "<label for="+inputID+">"+labelText+"</label>" after that you can add the boxLabel element whereever u want to add it using appendTo/prependTo

Comment: Thanks @gulty I am working on it.

Comment: @gulty I edited my original post. I do not know how to give proper id and to set label for the id.

Comment: I really need your html markup to help you further. I need to see how you are generating those checkboxes or how they are supposed to be generated. Like your .click element. And BTW. your variables start with '$' - thats a really bad practice since this is javascript and not PHP.

Comment: @gulty I just edited original post to add html at the bottom. You must be right about $! (Before I decided to add Labels, my script generated click buttons as expected).

Comment: @gulty I am on my way, your help was very beneficial, thank you.